# Replacing one fragment with other in viewpager

Tags: android

I'm using a `ViewPager` together with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to host four different fragments.

What I'm trying to achieve is to successfully replace `Fragment1` with a whole new fragment, `newFragment`,on click of a button.

When I use..

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1_layout_id, newfragment);
transaction.remove(fragment1);
transaction.commit();
```

The fragment is replaced  and `Fragment` is shown instead of `Fragment1`. Though as soon as I swipe all the way to `Fragment4` and then back to `newFragment`, `Fragment1` has made a comeback.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragments are provided by `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

You would need to adapt what fragment your `FragmentPagerAdapter` creates for your Fragment1 and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

With your approach, the time Fragment1 should be shown again, the `ViewPager` will simply ask your `FragmentPagerAdapter` to re-create the specific instance - which will give you back the instance you were trying to replace.

Not that `ViewPager` can cache fragments internally, as long as `notifyDataSetChanged()` was not called on the adapter. Hence, it may not pick up chances you have made without that call.

Comment: thanks for the reply  As i am using 'FragmentPageAdapter' does i have to explicitly write the code for 'notifyDataSetChanged()' and where should i write it.